# antialias text in scanned pdfs with opensource tools

Tags: pdf, imagemagick

I often scan letters or other text to pdfs with the normal Scan Utility on Mac OS with 300 dpi and the "Text" setting.
The files are small and normally good to read, but the text is very pixelated. Is there any open source tool (like imagemagick, ghostscript etc.) with which I can improve/antialias the text quality?
Or do I have the wrong way? Is it better to scan the files in grayscale and use some tools afterwards?

EDIT: As I'm getting no answers, I'm adding some more details, because the last days I played a little bit with imagemagick to achieve my goal.

So maybe I can specify my question: How can I antialias the text of the scanned pages?

Comment: Antialiasing is an optical trick to enhance pure visual quality. However, the usual way to achieve it is to take a large sample and downsample that. Surely trying to "enhance" existing low-rez text into a higher quality is something you only see in "CSI"? You might be better off using OCR -- "text" is *always* of the Best Possible quality.

Comment: The text is scanned with 300dpi and I want to keep this resolution, because the files are proposed to be shared and maybe someone wants to print the files.
What do you mean with using OCR in this case? Completely erase the image in the pdf and replace it with text?